# Ant replace text with special characters

Tags: xml, ant

This should be pretty simple. I want to open a file, search for a string, and then replace that string with a string that has special characters in it:

```
<replace file="${src}/index.html" token="</copyright>"
value="</copyright> <legalnotice xml:id="DocLegalNotice" xml:base="../../../reusable-content/legal-notice.xml" xml:lang="">"/>
```

When I run this, the build doesn't like the special characters:

```
The value of attribute "token" associated with an element type "replace"
must not contain the '<' character.
```

Do I have to escape every special character for "token" and "value", or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first problem is that an ant file must be a well-formed XML file, and well-formed XML cannot have `<` characters in attribute values.   Use `&lt;` instead.

Your second problem is that an attribute value delimited by double quote characters (`"`) cannot have unescaped embedded double quote characters.  Use `'` instead.

```
<replace file="${src}/index.html" 
         token="&lt;/copyright>"
         value="&lt;/copyright> &lt;legalnotice xml:id='DocLegalNotice' xml:base='../../../reusable-content/legal-notice.xml' xml:lang=''>"/>
```

At least your ant file will be well-formed, but really, doing replaces against an XML file by treating it as text is a bit of a hack.  Better would be to use an XML-based tool (such as XSLT) to make such changes.